# problem in mysqli query - timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, mysqli

i have a problem with my query.

fields in the database (`userid, code, timestamp`)

I want to verify in this code if exists an userid and the respective code but that was inserted less than one day, otherwise show a message "link expired"

My code works well without this line `TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURTIME(), timestamp) < 1")`.

At the moment nothing is returned with the timestamp condition

```
"select userid, code from password_reset  where userid=? and code=? and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURTIME(), timestamp) < 1"
```

There is some problem in this code? Basically my idea is: if the timestamp has more than a day, return an error to the user.

my script (the problem is only in the timestamp condition in the query)

```
if (checkBd ($sql, $db, $user, $codePass)){
            $user = (int)mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userid);
            $codePass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['code']);

            ($sql = $db->prepare("select userid, code from password_reset  where userid=? and code=? and TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURTIME(), timestamp) < 1"));

            $sql->bind_param('ss', $user, $codePass);

            $sql->execute();

            $sql->bind_result($user, $codePass);

            if ($sql->fetch()) {
                    $_SESSION['u_name']= sha1($user);
                    header("location: updatePass.php");
                    return true;
            }

    }
            $sql->close();
    $db->close();
```

Comment: What is the problem? is the problem with server time offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pass a `DATETIME` value, not just a `TIME`, use `NOW()` not `CURTIME()`. (If you want to ignore the time of day, then use `CURDATE()`.

Also, reverse the argument order, as the function does `datetime2 - datetime1`.

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for more details.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `timestamp`, NOW()) < 1
```

Using a reserved word for your column name won't help either.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks (i accepted your answer because is more completed)

Answer (score 1):

`CURTIME()` returns curent time (without date). I suppose the date used there by `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is 'min_date', try using instead `CURDATE()`